# How to get a regular expression to match items with spaces

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, regex

The following regular expression works if there is no space character, but if the input has a space character, it doesn't work (it seems like a link but JavaScript doesn't work).

How can I change it?

The regular expression should work for both `World` and `The World`.

```
    Dim makebkz As String
    Dim pattern As String = "\(bkz: ([a-z0-9$&.öışçğü\s]+)\)"
    Dim regex As New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim myAnchor As New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor()
    Dim postbackRef As String = Page.GetPostBackEventReference(myAnchor, "$1")
    myAnchor.HRef = postbackRef

    str = regex.Replace(str, "(bkz: <a href=javascript:" & myAnchor.HRef & "><font color=""#CC0000"">$1</font></a> )")
    makebkz = str
    Return makebkz
```

Comment: You're saying "it doesn't redirect" - do you mean that the returned link (makebkz) doesn't work on the page? Or do you mean the regex doesn't perform a replace when str is "The World"? What is being returned?

Comment: I think you're going to have to clear up some details of the what input the regex is matching against.  I tried input of "(bkz: World)" and "(bkz: The World)" and was able to get a match on both with your code.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line should be changed:

```
str = regex.Replace(str, "(bkz: <a href=javascript:" & myAnchor.HRef & "><font color=""#CC0000"">$1</font></a> )")
```

If I read your code correctly you are including the $1 in the HRef (that's what the Page.GetPostBackEventReference(myAnchor, "$1") is doing), and then replacing it in both the text between the font tags and the href, so your output would be something like:

```
(bkz: <a href=javascript:__doPostBack(The World)><font color=""#CC0000"">The World</font></a> )
```

If you update your replace function to this, it should work:

```
str = regex.Replace(str, "(bkz: <a href=""javascript:" & myAnchor.HRef & """><font color=""#CC0000"">$1</font></a> )")
```

I.e. wrap the javascript call in quotes, and your world will be good.

Comment: Thanks Zhaph,Your solution worked.it didnt depend on regular expressions.Thanks everybody

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a space 'character'.  It is a '\s' (minus the quotes).

Answer (score 1):

**\s** will match any whitespace character.  Be sure to escape this properly.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, are you saying that something like `(bkz: world)` works, but `(bkz: the world)` does not?

The regex you currently have will match both (verfied in RegexBuddy), and your capture group should be fine (it should capture `world` in the first case and `the world` in the second).

What is being stored in `str` after your call to `Replace` in the case where things aren't working?  My guess is that the string you're generating is where the problem is, not the regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

try making the space character conditional \s* means there can be 0 or many spaces between the bkz: block.  You can also use \s? if there are 0 or 1 spaces.

```
Dim pattern As String = "\(bkz:\s*([a-z0-9$&.öışçğü\s]+)\)"
```

Although since your second pattern contains a match for a space you may have to expand your expression to state that the first character in the parenthisized match isn't a space  here is a sample for that.

```
Dim pattern As String = "\(bkz:\s*([a-z0-9$&.öışçğü][a-z0-9$&.öışçğü\s]+)\)"
```